# Read csv files with double quotes and comma delimiter, containing doubles and strings (arbitrary number of rows and columns)

Tags: matlab, csv

I am reading csv files with the following format:

```
Header:,Date,Time,"MC2_Y241_TightnessPressValve","MC2_Y243_PressingValve""
Data,2015-09-16,15:41:52;781,"780.000000","0.0034"
Data,2015-09-16,15:41:52;791,"790.000000","0.1255"
Data,2015-09-16,15:41:52;801,"800.000000","1.5123"
```

Atm I am using fgetl(fid) to find the headers and all the dates and times. Then I use the knowledge of which rows and columns are containing doubles, to be able to use csvread() for fast reading. However, to use csvread(), I must first remove the quotes. I am currently doing this with a powershell script within matlab but it is too time consuming as I will need to read files of +200Mb.

Note: textscan with '%q' cannot be used for two reasons:
1) I want all doubles to be read as doubles immediately (converting is too time consuming).
2) The files contain various numbers of rows and columns.

This is for a standalone application.

I truly appreciate all help, I have spent countless hours on making this efficient.

Comment: various numbers of rows and columns? It's ok to have any number of rows. but you need to know the format of the columns.

Comment: I could use fgetl and check the string for the number of delimiters (commas) and findout how many columns I have. But where do I go from there?

Comment: read the header line `f = fopen(file,'r'); h = f.getl(f);`, split by delimiter `cols = regexp(h, ',', 'split');`, then you get a cell string array containing the name of each column. you can know the number of column by `ncol = length(cols);` From the value of each item of `cols`, you can know what this column is as well as the datatype. then you can construct a format string according that.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I got it to work now, however, it's still very time consuming. I tried a 190Mb file and manually interrupted after 7 minutes loading time (16 GB ram and intel core i7-4810MQ 2.8GHz). Any ideas for faster reading?

Comment: read into a string `s = fileread(you_file);` then use `textscan(s, format)`. if the quote is a trouble, use `s = strrep(s,'"','')` to remove the quotes.

Comment: If I do that, I will have all my values as strings. Using str2double demands a lot of computation power as well. Or is there any way to remove the quotes and interpret as double immediately?

Comment: read the help doc of `textscan`, especially the `formatSpec` part

Comment: Fantastic, Lee!!! Thank you so much! It works great!

Comment: Not sure if you were notified @Lee but in case the solution is of interest, you may find it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though I should post an answer, in case anyone else has the same problem. Acknowledgements to [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5373131/lee) who helped me with this!

```
% Remove quotes
fid = fopen('temp.csv','w');
s = fileread('myFile.csv');
s = strrep(s,'"','');
fprintf(fid,s);
fclose(fid);

% Open new, quote free, file
fid = fopen('temp.csv','r');

% Get Headers
Headers{1} = fgetl(fid);
Headers = textscan(Headers{1},'%s','Delimiter',',');
Headers = Headers{1};
Headers = Headers(3:end);

% Get date and time
lineIndex = 1;
nextLine = fgetl(fid);
time{lineIndex} = nextLine(6:28);
lineIndex = lineIndex + 1;
nextLine = fgetl(fid);
while ~isequal(nextLine,-1) && ~isempty(nextLine)
    time{lineIndex} = nextLine(6:28);
    lineIndex = lineIndex + 1;
    nextLine = fgetl(fid);
end

% Get doubles
Data = csvread('temp.csv', 1,3);
fclose(fid);

% Convert time with datenum
Time = datenum(time,'yyyy-mm-dd,HH:MM:SS;FFF');

% Put all data in one matrix
Data = [Time, Data];
```